# SQL: DATE_ADD inside an if statement inside a select statemt

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select a date. If it is yesterday or beyond I want add one year in MySQL.
I only got problem with the select statement:

```
SELECT orade.*, IF(orade.date < '$today', DATE_ADD(orade.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), orade.date) AS realDate
```

$today is `'2011-11-04'`

Comment: what problems did you find when you ran this? Error? Unexpected result?

Comment: Syntax error beginning at the end of the if statement's right parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `CASE` and not `IF`? I don't think `IF` can be used the way you're using it in MySQL.

```
SELECT orade.*, CASE WHEN orade.date < '$today'
                          THEN DATE_ADD(orade.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
                     ELSE orade.date
                END AS realDate
```

Comment: But I have used if before in the select statement? it should work

Comment: It may support the If, but I've never used it like that, only like this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html.

Comment: There is no issue with your use of the if statement, I often do this. I have translated your query on one of my tables and it works. Maybe your $today variable is guilty ? You could echo the string sent to mysql.